# Integral of little o

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I know that there are already a couple of questions regarding this topic here on MathSE but none could give me a satisfying answer so far...

I am dealing with the integral $$\int \Big(f(x) + o(h^2x^2)\Big)\mathrm dx,$$ where $o$ is understood with regard to $h\rightarrow 0$. Apparently, the result is $$o(h^2) + \int f(x),$$ assuming that $\int x^2f(x) = const$. So it seems like little $o$ and integral were interchanged . But how can that be justified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember $f(h) = o(g(h))$ if:

$\begin{align*}
   \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)}{g(h)}
     &= 0
\end{align*}$

By the definition of the limit (assuming positive functions!) this means that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta$ such that for $\lvert h  \rvert \le \delta$:

$\begin{align*}
   \left\lvert \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right\rvert
      &\le \epsilon \\
   f(h)
      &\le \epsilon g(h)
\end{align*}$

In your case:

$\begin{align*}
   u(x)
     &= o(x^2 h^2) \\
   u(x)
     &\le \epsilon x^2 h^2 \\
   \int_{x_0}^{x_1} u(x) \, d x
     &\le \epsilon h^2 \int_{x_0}^{x_1} x^2 \, d x \\
     &=   \epsilon h^2 \frac{x_1^3 - x_0^3}{3} \\
     &=   o(h^2)
\end{align*}$